# How to skip all test from setUpClass

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-unittest

I want to skip all the unit-tests if some condition doesn't satisfy under `setUpClass` function. Like -

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    if(!condition):
        cls.skipTest("For some reason")
```

After doing this I'm expecting other unittest cases will not run. But it's showing an error

> TypeError: skipTest() missing 1 required  positional argument: 'reason'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can raise the `SkipTest` exception like:

```
@classmethod
def setUpClass(cls):
    if not condition:
        raise unittest.SkipTest("For some reason")
```